# How to void an invoice using InvoiceModRq in QBFC xml?

Tags: qbfc

I can add new invoices, edit previously added ones, add/edit/delete line items, etc. But I can't find any info on how exactly to void an invoice using InvoiceModRq. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use the AppendTxnVoidRq message to void any transaction. (To delete, there is an equivalent AppendTxnDeleteRq.) You set the TxnVoidType and TxnID properties and then execute the SessionManager.DoRequest as usual.

Below is an example in C#.

```
ITxnVoid rqVoid = rqMsgSet.AppendTxnVoidRq();
rqVoid.TxnVoidType.SetValue(ENTxnVoidType.tvtInvoice);
rqVoid.TxnID.SetValue("<TxnID>"); //Should be in this format: 21734D-1418350079.
```